# Microsoft translator returns error

Tags: android, microsoft-translator

I am trying to build an app that translate the current city to english.
this is my code:

```
class translateAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        Translate.setClientId("xxx");
        Translate.setClientSecret("yyy");
        try {
            translatedText = Translate.execute(location, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.ENGLISH);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            translatedText = e.getMessage();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is my call to async task:

```
new translateAsync() {
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                if (translatedText.contains("Error")){
                    lblCbProfileLayoutCurrentCity.setText(translatedText);
                } else {
                    lblCbProfileLayoutCurrentCity.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.user_profile_code_current_city)
                            + translatedText);
                }
                Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, translatedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }.execute();
```

I keep getting this error:

[microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation: https://datamarket.access-control.windows.net/v2/qauth2-13
Please Help Me.

Comment: Did you look up the error?

Comment: Thanks for posting your API keys/id... you will probably want to go get those changed, IMMEDIATELY.

Comment: Please post the error. You should also try googling it, too.

Comment: I googled it already, didn't find the answer. i posted the error: [microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation: https://datamarket.access-control.windows.net/v2/qauth2-13. someone said it's because i've made to many calls but it's the first time I have used the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
I didn't register my app in the azure market correctly and because of it i got a wrong secret key.
if anyone needs help with registering correctly you can email me.